# Persisting Images in App - Android Kotlin Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Newbie here.

How can I save images to my app after I load them from the gallery?
I want to build a project where the user can take a picture, write a description about the picture, and save all of that in a Room database or DataStore app so all of the photos they've taken are there when they open the app later.

I can't figure out the best way to persist the images. I've heard saving images into a Room database is bad practice so not sure what to do. Any advice is very much appreciated!

Comment: The images are already saved in the gallery, right? Then it is enough to save their URI in the database. An important point - to save the URI you need to get permission, see: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html

Comment: Also look here: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#persist-permissions

Answer (score 0):

You can save it after picking it. Here is han example

```
fun saveImageToInternalStorage(context: Context, uri: Uri): String {
    val fileName = UUID.randomUUID().toString() + ".jpg"
    val inputStream = context.contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)
    val outputStream = context.openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    inputStream?.use { input ->
        outputStream.use { output ->
            input.copyTo(output)
        }
    }

    return fileName
}

@Composable
fun PickImage() {
   val image = remember { mutableStateOf("") }

    val context = LocalContext.current
    val getContent = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
        contract = ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()
    ) { uri: Uri? ->

        uri?.let {
            image.value = saveImageToInternalStorage(context, it)
        }
    }

    Image(
        painter = rememberAsyncImagePainter(File(LocalContext.current.filesDir, image.value)),

        contentDescription = null,
        contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .clip(CircleShape)
    )

    if (image.value.isEmpty()) {
        SideEffect {
            getContent.launch("image/*")
        }
    }
}
```